# Почему у spring бина методы toString() и hashCode() дают разные результаты?

Tags: java, spring, hashcode, bean

Есть класс с аннотацией `@RequestScope`:

```java
@Component
@RequestScope
public class ComponentRequestScope {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

`hashCode()` и `toString()` у него не переопределены.
И есть контроллер, который использует этот класс:

```java
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    private ComponentRequestScope component;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String loginGet() {
        System.out.println(component + " - " + Integer.toHexString(component.hashCode()));
        return "login.html";
    }
}
```

Если сделать запрос, то получается такой ответ:

> ComponentRequestScope@3be1a523 - 16035cfa

Кроме того, если сделать еще запрос, получается следующий ответ:

> ComponentRequestScope@3575d568 - 16035cfa

Почему получается разный хэш при работе не переопределенных методов `toString()` и `hashCode()`?
Почему при работе метода `hashCode()` при двух запросах одинаковый хэш, ведь объекты должны быть разные?

Comment: а где собственно видно, что "получается разный хэш"? в примерах он одинаковый

Comment: 2. Вы считаете, что объекты разные, точно проверили (сравнили через `equals`)? Подозреваю, что они всё же одинаковые в смысле `equals` и тогда `hashCode()` делает то, что должен: возвращает для них одинаковое значение

Comment: Ожидаются разные объекты так как ComponentRequestScope помечен аннотацией @RequestScope, которая должна обеспечить новый бин при каждом запросе

Comment: А какое имеет отношение то, что объекты разные (в том смысле, что их в памяти 2 и ссылки не равны) к тому, что объекты равны в смысле равенства через `equals()`, что в свою очередь приводит к равенству `hashCode()`. Поэтому ещё раз, вы сравнили их через `equals` (или хотя бы просто глазами через дебагер)?

Answer (score 4):

Все дело в том, что spring перехватывает выполнение методов `toString()` и `hashCode()`.
При выполнении метода `toString()` выполняется метод `intercept()` класса `DynamicAdvisedInterceptor` вложенного в класс `CglibAopProxy`.
При выполнении метода `hashCode()` выполняется метод `intercept()` класса HashCodeInterceptor вложенного так же в `CglibAopProxy`.
Если посмотреть на последний метод:

```
private static class HashCodeInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor, Serializable {
    private final AdvisedSupport advised;

    public HashCodeInterceptor(AdvisedSupport advised) {
        this.advised = advised;
    }

    public Object intercept(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy methodProxy) {
        return CglibAopProxy.class.hashCode() * 13 + this.advised.getTargetSource().hashCode();
    }
}
```

получается что он вычисляет hashCode у класса `CglibAopProxy` и объекта, полученного из `this.advised.getTargetSource()`. При этом не используя переданный объект `Object proxy` (который component).
Следовательно `hashCode()` зависит от Spring Boot, его классов и объектов, и никак не зависит самого объекта класса `ComponentRequestScope`.